# Only encrypt mails when possible

Tags: c#, encryption, outlook, certificate, smime

Is it possible to only encrypt mail when its possible. 
I wrote an Add-In which auto forward mails. The Add-In stops when it tries to encrypt a mail which cant be ecrypted. For example when there is no public key for the recipient. 
I tried to catch and handle throwed exception, but in this case there is no exception thrown. Any ideas? 
This is the Method I talk about.

```
 private void signAndEncrypt(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
    {
        const string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";

        Object ulFlags = 0x3;

        mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS,ulFlags);
    }
```

heres a screenshot of the error. Its in german.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7JI5.jpg)

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: For sure, sorry.
i edited the post :)

Comment: What is the exact error and which OOM method causes it?

Comment: Its not a real error. The Method i added in the Post will sign and encrypt the mail. If Outlook cant encrypt the mail, for example when there is no public key for the recipient, Outlook will give a message that it cant encrypt the message and ask if I want to send it unencrypted. As long as i dont react to this messagebox the addin will stop working.